# Should I fetch by Id from API or filter fetched data

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I want to know what is the best approach for my problem. If I have 1 array of products that I have already fetched from my API, and now I want to get one single product. Should I filter the fetched data or should I make another API request by product Id?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your need.

If the details of the product are on another page, I would say that you should have another API request in case of the user arrives directly on the details page with the URL, or simply if he refreshes the details page.

If not, a simple filter can be enough.

Answer (score -1):

Filter the fetched data. Reading data in memory will always be faster than making another api request.